# Scrapy CSV crawling

Tags: python, scrapy

'm trying to crawl some rows from CSV file using CSVFeedSpider
The structure of the file is the next:
id | category | price
I need to crawl the rows which only have a spefic category "paid"
I do the next:

```
class Outillage_spider(CSVFeedSpider):
name = 'domain.com'
allowed_domains = ['domain.com', 'www.domain.com']
start_urls = ('http://www.domain.com/file.csv',)

delimiter = ';'
headers = ['name', 'category', 'price']

def parse_row(self, response, row):
    categories = ['Bosch','Dolmar','Fein','Hitachi','Karcher','Leman','Makita','SDMO','Ski']
if row['category'] in categories:
        res = {}
        res['name'] = row['name']
        res['price'] = row['price']
        return load_product(res, response)
    else:
  return None
```

And the next I got:

```
      File "/home/rolikoff/web/scrapy_projects/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-0.14.1-py2.7.egg/scrapy/contrib/spiders/feed.py", line 129, in parse_rows
    raise TypeError('You cannot return an "%s" object from a spider' % type(ret).__name__)
exceptions.TypeError: You cannot return an "NoneType" object from a spider
```

I think it happens when parse_row() returns None. But I'm not sure how to change the fucthion. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks
Dmitry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to return empty `list` or `tuple` instead `None`

```
else:
    return []
```

And make sure, that `load_product` returns `list`, `tuple`, `Item` or `Request`

Answer (score 1):

As far I am concerned you have to yield fields within the parse_row ! for example, this is an spider that I did for crawling of Podcasts URLs : 
https://github.com/arthurnn/podcast/blob/master/podcast/spiders/itunes_spider.py

I would remove the else! try this out:

```
  if row['category'] in categories:
        res = {}
        res['name'] = row['name']
        res['price'] = row['price']
        yield load_product(res, response)
```

However if you are not using a normal spider! For a CSVFeedSpider read my Edit bellow:

**EDIT**

In this case you have to return a BaseItem or a list or a tuple! if you look at the implementation of CSVFeedSpider http://dev.scrapy.org/browser/scrapy/contrib/spiders/feed.py?rev=1516 ! you will see that

Comment: It doesn't allow to use yueld   File "/home/rolikoff/web/scrapy_projects/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-0.14.1-py2.7.egg/scrapy/contrib/spiders/feed.py", line 129, in parse_rows
     raise TypeError('You cannot return an "%s" object from a spider' % type(ret).__name__)
 exceptions.TypeError: You cannot return an "generator" object from a spider

Comment: Ok, I've found the solution
Replace

    return None

with

    return ()

Thanks anyway!